# Create a Web API without top-level statements

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, dotnet-cli

I am using dotnet cli to create an **ASP.NET Core Web API**

```
dotnet new webapi --output WebAPI;
```

Is it possible to create it but  without top-level statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `--use-program-main` switch (or `--use-program-main true`) for the `dotnet new` command:

```bash
dotnet new webapi --output WebAPI --use-program-main
```

Note that this will just generate `Main` method. The minimal hosting model will still be used (so no `Startup`).

Comment: @paulroho [docs claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style) that it was introduced in  .NET SDK 6.0.300 version.

Comment: thank you very much for the correction. I deleted my misleading comment.